# Outlook Js Addin with SSO throw error for other Tenants

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have created a very basic Outlook Js add-in with SSO . The addin is registered in `Tenant A` as Multitenant allowing any Azure AD directory and Personal Microsoft Accounts to use it. It works well for all users of that tenant,  however if another user of `Tenant B` is sideloading the addin he receives the `13004 Invalid application resource Url provided`. The settings in the manifest are correct as users of Tenant A use the addin without any error. Am I missing any step with mutlitenancy? How users from any tenant can use it?
Below is just a snipper from the addin

```
async function getGraphData() {
try {
    let bootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken();
}
catch (exception) {
    if (exception.code === 13003) {
        // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
        // Microsoft 365 Education or work account, or a Microsoft account.
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

and Manifest snippet

```
      <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>{GUID}</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/{GUID}</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
          <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
        </Scopes>
      </WebApplicationInfo>
```

Comment: According to your error message: Invalid application resource Url provided, try to change it to: `<Resource>api://{your client id}/.default</Resource>`

Comment: I cannot see that url format in the Azure Config ? can you point to documentation which suggest that ? thx

Comment: @Jim Check if this documentation helps in debugging the issue you are facing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#13004
If not, please let do us know in which platform you are seeing this issue.